# How can an Infinity Group have the identity element e if e=e²=e³=...?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

From the definitions of [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Infinite_Cyclic_Group) whe have that an Infinite Cyclic Group G is a [Cyclic Group](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cyclic_Group), such that: 
Definition 2: $∀a∈G:∀m,n∈Z:m≠n⟹a^m≠a^n$.

But we know that if e is the identity element, e²=e³ and so on.
What i'm missing here?

Comment: On ProofWiki it is written $a\neq e$ before. But yes, it should also be repeated in definition $2$.

Comment: You are correct, this is an oversight on their part. The first definition given is correct.

Comment: Fixed it back in May

Answer (score 3):

You are missing nothing. Instead of $\forall a\in G$, it should have been $\forall a\in G\setminus\{e\}$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assume $a\neq e$.